# Agregar tarjeta: Code 120 - Card not found... Agregar suscripción a customer: Code 2010 - Security code mandatory

Tags: api, rest, mercadopago

El problema en el que estamos atorados es el siguiente:

1. Desde front se capturan los datos de la tarjeta de crédito/debito, para que genere el token de dicha tarjeta. El token es enviado a nuestro servidor backend junto con los datos de "customer"
2. Haciendo POST desde nuestro servidor backend hacia `https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/customers` se envían los parámetros del "customer" recibido desde frontend. Se captura el id del nuevo cliente creado

Una vez creado el nuevo "customer" se hace POST hacia `https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/customers/:customer_id:/cards` en la cual se incluye el JSON:

```
{
    "token": "tokenRecibidoDesdeFront"
}
```

Arrojando el error

```
{
    "code":120,
    "description": "card not found"
}
```

Hubo ocasiones en las que no arrojó el error, y la tarjeta fue asignada correctamente al "customer", pero no logramos identificar un patrón que nos indique el motuivo por el cuál fue aceptada la tarjeta.

4. Cuando no hubo error al agregar la tarjeta, se hace POST a `https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/subscriptions` con los valores:

   {
       "plan_id": "7886c889...",
       "payer": { "id":"customer_id"}
    }

El plan fue creado anteriormente por medio de POST `https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/plans` y tiene los valores:

```
{
    "id": "7886c889028548feb02d32aa7f1e734d",
    "application_fee": null,
    "status": "active",
    "description": "Plan basico",
    "external_reference": null,
    "date_created": "2017-07-13T12:28:25.000-04:00",
    "last_modified": "2017-07-17T21:26:56.000-04:00",
    "auto_recurring": {
        "frequency": 1,
        "frequency_type": "months",
        "transaction_amount": 10,
        "currency_id": "MXN",
        "repetitions": null,
        "debit_date": null,
        "free_trial": {
            "frequency": null,
            "frequency_type": null
        }
    },
    "live_mode": true,
    "setup_fee": null,
    "metadata": null
}
```

En esta ocasión el error que se recibió fue

```
{
    "code": 2010,
    "description": "Security code mandatory - This payment method doesn't allow recurring payments"
}
```

No sabemos que hemos estado realizando mal, ya que en modo SANDBOX haciendo el mismo procedimiento no hay ningún problema

Comment: Sumaria, que puedas añadir algunos datos como el país en el que estas realizando la integración y el tipo de tarjeta que estas usando (visa/debito) por ejemplo, para validar si no es una restricción del servicio ya que los mensajes de error me parecen eso.